# General elementary prime numbers divisibility question

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a, b$ be non-negative integers and $p\ge3$ be a prime number. If $a^2+b^2$ and $a+b$ are divisible by $p$ does it mean $a$ and $b$ are always divisible by $p$?

Comment: Yes, it is true. Try to show that $a-b$ is also divisible by $p$,  from the fact that $(a-b)^2$ is a multiple of $p$. Note that this is not true for $p = 2$.

Comment: Note that $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab$ and use Euclid's lemma to conclude that $p$ must divide $a$ or $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $p$ be an odd prime.

Note that $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab$ and use Euclid's lemma to conclude that $p$ must divide $a$ or $b$.

Now, assume that **only one** of $a,b$ (WLOG say $a$) is divisible by $p$.

Since $p\mid a+b$ and $p\mid a$, we get $p\mid (a+b)-a=b$, i.e., $p\mid b$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a+b\equiv 0 \bmod p$, we have $a\equiv -b $ and thus $ a^2\equiv b^2 \bmod p$.

Then $a^2+b^2\equiv 2a^2 \equiv 0 \bmod p$ and since $p>2$ we know $p\mid a^2$ and thus $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$.